# Laravel - Multi Auth Email Confirmation

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel [Hesto Multi Auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth) package to create multiple auth. I have not used the default auth, but created user, admin, support, professionals guards with laravel hesto

Now im trying to implement Laravel email confirmation using [this package](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel-email-confirmation)

This send me a activation link to my email. However when that routes to http://localhost:8000/confirmation/2/jOVjV2xkfRZqAM4nwjAKdwTwn2 it shows an error

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::confirm does not exist.
```

It should check in App\Http\Controllers\UserAuth\RegisterController::confirm

How to change this? Also would like to know how to implement the same for other guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel-email-confirmation/blob/master/routes/web.php you will note they have defined routes for this. You can override this by doing the following:

1) Disable auto-discover for the package on the `dont-discover` portion of your `compopser.json` file.

2) Register the package's service provider before `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class` so you can override the registered routes on your application.

3) Go ahead and register the routes you want, which will probably be like this:

```
Route::get('confirmation/resend', 'UserAuth\RegisterController@resend');
Route::get('confirmation/{id}/{token}', 'UserAuth\RegisterController@confirm');
```

That should do it or at least get you in the right track.

Also ensure you `use` the package Traits on your UserAuth controllers.

Comment: Thanks! That works! How to update this for multi auth users. I have another auth that is professionals. When i use the traits/routes in them same as i did for users, i receive an email with activation but the button url it shows page not found. How to solve this? This could also be a suggestion on the package github